# Calculate time difference based on user input

Tags: java, android

How do I calculate time difference in java based on user input? Below is a working code snippet.

```
@Override
            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view,int hourofDay, int minute)
            {

                if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
                    start.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + "." + Integer.toString(minute));
                     b=start.getText().toString();
                } else if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
                    end.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + "." + Integer.toString(minute));
                     c=end.getText().toString();
                    //endTime=hourofDay;
                }

                SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
                Date date1=format.parse(b);
                Date date2=format.parse(c);
                long difference=date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
                editText.setText(""+difference);


            }


        }
```

error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Comment: Do exactly as suggested by the error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your error, it was cause by ParseException, you can fix it by adding try and catch.

```
try{
       // do your calculation here
       // for your case will be:
            SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
            Date date1=format.parse(b);
            Date date2=format.parse(c);
            long difference=date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
            editText.setText(""+difference);
    }
    catch(ParseException ex){
            System.err.println("ouch!");
    }
```

You can then convert the total different millisecond into hours, minutes, seconds, and etc.

```
int seconds = (int) (difference/ 1000) % 60 ;
int minutes = (int) ((difference/ (1000*60)) % 60);
int hours   = (int) ((difference/ (1000*60*60)) % 24);
//etc...
```

Comment: Thanks, but why it does not display the value(difference) to editText?

Comment: try change your `.` to `:` since your format is `:`

Comment: Always remember to catch the most specific exception - in this case ParseException.

Answer (score 1):

You need to catch the ParseException that could be thrown from the `parse()` calls:

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date date1=format.parse(b);
    Date date2=format.parse(c);
    long difference=date2.getTime()-date1.getTime();
    editText.setText(""+difference);
} catch (ParseException pe) {
    editText.setText("Failed to parse dates"); // or whatever you want
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `.` separator with `:` separator for time and rest works cool

```
 if (flag == FLAG_START_DATE) {
                    start.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                     b=start.getText().toString();
                } else if (flag == FLAG_END_DATE) {
                    end.setText(Integer.toString(hourofDay) + ":" + Integer.toString(minute));
                     c=end.getText().toString();
                    //endTime=hourofDay;
                }
```